# bypass findBy in symfony2 forcing lowercase as first letter

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

if I try to run this query in symfony2

```
$karte = $em->getRepository('CQIntranetBundle:Karte')->findByPGuId($pguid);
```

its returns

```
Entity 'CQ\IntranetBundle\Entity\Karte' has no field 'pGuId'. You can therefore not call 'findByPGuId' on the entities' repository
```

the field PGuID exist but the query try to look for pGuId is there a fix for this?

Comment: Did you try `findBy(["PGuId" => $pguid])`?

Comment: What do you have in your mapping for the field in your entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the method in the Karte repository :

```
public function findByPGuId($PGuId) {
   return $this->createQueryBuilder('k')
     ->where('k.PGuId= :PGuId')        
     ->setParameter('PGuId',$PGuId)      
     ->getQuery()
     ->getResult();                     
}
```